# In Angular,openWeatherMap

Tags: openweathermap

how to solve api key poroblems in the open weather map

i try to get the city and min and max temperature and i expected also.
the values came in the browser but not came the console why?
the error is open this is came

```json
{"coord":{"lon":76.95,"lat":11.01},
 "weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}],
 "base":"stations",
 "main":{
   "temp":296.93,
   "feels_like":297.53,
   "temp_min":296.93,
   "temp_max":301.11,
   "pressure":1015,
   "humidity":83},
 "visibility":3500,
 "wind":{"speed":2.06,"deg":70},
 "clouds":{"all":75},
 "dt":1702357117,
 "sys":{
   "type":1,
   "id":9206,
   "country":"IN",
   "sunrise":1702342862,
   "sunset":1702384227},
 "timezone":19800,
 "id":1273865,
 "name":"Coimbatore",
 "cod":200}
```

but that is not came the console

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the error that you are getting in the console? How do you access the API, are you using browser console, `curl` or some kind of programming language?